# "Experienced" vs. "seasoned"

Tags: meaning, differences, adjectives

Are these two words interchangeable?

According to the Oxford dictionary, *experienced* means having knowledge or skill in a particular job or activity, while *seasoned* having a lot of experience in a particular activity. But, people still do say "seasoned pilot".

Then, what is the difference these two?

Answer (score 16):

The two are often used interchangeably.

That said, a Google search of "seasoned by experience" (in quotes) comes up with many examples of that phrase being used by legitimate publications, including by some dictionaries in the example sentences attributed to *seasoned*.

This points to the fact that the two words can have different implications. [*Seasoned*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/seasoned) really means something closer to *matured*. Because people typically mature as a result of experience, the conflation of the two words is understandable. However, there are plenty of people out there who've had a world of experience and have yet to grow up.

Answer (score 6):

As with so many near synonyms, the choice depends on style and context. To take a rather trivial example, a writer may want to use *seasoned* simply because *experienced* has already appeared three lines earlier.

Comment: Yes - you'd have to think twice before using seasoned with an old salt.

Answer (score 5):

Agree that these two are often interchangeable but context and implication provides a clue - Experience is repetitive exposure whereas seasoning is the maturation process that occurs as a result of this. One can have had plenty of experience but if nothing has been learned as a result, one would not be considered seasoned.  See [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/seasoned?q=seasoned) for this definition . . . 'having a lot of experience of doing something *and therefore* knowing how to do it well'

Answer (score 3):

Anyone can be experienced, not all are seasoned. It depends on how much you learn and internalize from experience. *Seasoned*, therefore, is used for people who are experts by virtue of rich and beneficial experience.

Answer (score 0):

*Seasoned* means knowing a task so well that you "inheritantly" know what is next. *Experienced* is knowing a task as well, but being cautious and ready for aberrations.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. As it stands this answer is incomplete. Please edit to tell *why* this is the right answer. Cite facts, references, or specific expertise. Thanks.

Comment: "inheritantly"? Do you mean, "inherently"? @MetaEd - this answer appears as the top Google result for "seasoned advice meaning".

Answer (score 0):

Seasoned is commanding based,having more reach to the real world.Experience is administrative based,more relative to the environment both internal and external.

Answer (score 0):

Seasoned means 'used to, accustomed, comfortable with'
Experience means 'gone through, experienced, endured' but experience doesn't means 'One is accustomed'.

Answer (score -2):

*Seasoned* implies expertise, while *experienced* refers to having knowledge of a certain issue.