# Can a story be "spiced up" or "flavoured" with details?

Tags: word-choice

I am thinking of a verb that could go with the "***story***" in a sense that it is *enhanced* with details, something like "*flavoured*", "*seasoned*", "*spiced (up?)*". But I only found that these three verbs usually go with food ingredients. Are there any possible connotations in English not directly relating to cookery and at the same time showing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are free to use such comparisons or figurative uses even if they are not attested. That said, people definitely use *spice up* (and even specific spices) to describe enlivening up a story or other non-food item. My first result was in the entry for *[mirch masala, n](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/61898380)." in the Oxford English Dictionary. It's literally a mixture of spices including chili. It also has a figurative use:

> 2. figurative (in Indian English). Interest, excitement, or piquancy; exaggeration or hyperbole, **esp. used to spice up a news story**. Cf. masala n. 2, mirch n. 2.

An English lexicographer saw fit to explain this usage by using the phrasing "used to *spice up* a news story." Indeed, "[spice, v.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186507)" has this meaning in 1b.:

> b. figurative. To season, to affect the character or quality of, by
>   means of some addition or modification; usually with with. Also
>   (colloquial) **with up, to enliven, to make more interesting or racy**.

Recent instances abound! A quick search on Google News for "spice up" featured nonliteral uses in half of the top results:

[image]

Out of your other two words, "seasoned" works less well because one common nonliteral use refers to people with more experience (a "[seasoned employee](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52081/experienced-vs-seasoned)"). Meanwhile, I had trouble finding non-literal uses of "flavored," though I've seen "flavor" as a noun used to describe variety, as [Merriam-Webster mentions](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flavor). You could use context to differentiate either of these, but they wouldn't be as well recognized. "Spiced up" is the *expression du jour* for enhancing a story.

Answer (score 1):

Those are food-related words, sure, but it is a common to use those to describe writing and all sorts of other things, in the sense of adding "spice" or "flavor" to make things more interesting or evocative ([The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/spice+up), [Glean](https://glean.info/how-to-add-flavor-to-your-writing-and-cut-out-the-fluff/)). "Seasoning" is probably less common in that context, but the beautiful thing of metaphor is that you can use words out of their normal place to describe anything you want to, really.

- "My story was fine, but I decided to add some background details for flavor."
- "You could try to spice up the story by describing more of the characters' interactions."
- "The storytelling is a little dry; perhaps it needs a bit more seasoning."

Answer (score 0):

"Spiced up" certainly works in this sense as a metaphor - "He spiced up his story with lots of juicy details." Check the second meaning here: https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/spice+up
You'd probably be understood if you used flavoured or seasoned, but they're not as commonly used as idioms in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your own word, enhance, is good. Google dictionary’s definition:

intensify, increase, or further improve the quality, value, or extent of.
"his refusal does nothing to enhance his reputation"
synonyms:   increase, add to, intensify, magnify, amplify, inflate, strengthen, build up, supplement, augment, boost, upgrade, raise, lift, escalate, elevate, exalt, aggrandize, swell; More
improve, enrich, complement, heighten, deepen, stress, reinforce, underline, emphasize;
informal: jack up, hike
"his dramatic appearance enhanced his reputation"